# How do I create a table name in MySQL using a select?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a MySQL event to make a copy of a table in the database with a `timestamp` in the name.

```
CREATE  TABLE  `db_name`.`tbl_prefix_(SELECT TO_SECONDS(NOW()))` ( [the rest...]
```

Obviously this isn't working. What should I do to make it work?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: this sounds like a really bad idea, even for a zombie

Comment: You probably want to look at MySQL partitioning by dates instead.

Comment: I can't see why this could do anything more than adding a timestamp field in a single table

Comment: creating tables should ONLY EVER be done at the beginning of setting up a database. There is such a thing as temporary tables, which are sometimes useful if you need to join / sort a lot of data -- as a method of optimization. You are nowhere near optimization. You are trying to do this completely the wrong way. Think of tables as a permanent, static, NEVER changing architecture of your system, and then figure out how to add data WITHIN THE TABLES. Creating and deleting tables is extremely dangerous (especially with user input) and slow, and impossible to search through.

Comment: WOW! Thanks for the feed back. That was much faster then I thought. Anyway, yes this is a temp table... but by the sounds of it.. its damn near impossible. I'll figure out a different solution. Thanks again

Comment: @ZombifiedHead you would have a lot more feedback if you actually stated what issue you were trying to resolve with that approach, as people would actually be able to evaluate and tell you the best route you could take to accomplish given all the experts around. *Just don't expect that the chock will actually bring you back to life.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you would need to use "dynamic SQL". That is, make use of the MySQL `PREPARE` statement.

What you'd need to do is populate a **variable** with a **string** that contains the SQL text you want to execute. Doing variable substitution into string is trivial.

The "trick" is to take that dynamic string and execute it like it was a SQL statement.

And that's what the `PREPARE` statement does for us, takes in a variable, and reads the contents of that variable like it were a SQL statement.

---

With that said, rather than give an example code that demonstrates this in more detail, I'm going to suggest that you re-think this idea of creating a table with timestamp value as part of the name.

What problem is that designed to solve? And carefully consider whether the proposed design for a solution will introduce a bigger problem than it solves.

Comment: the answer's off topic because this guy isn't even approaching using prepared statements -- he's trying to create tables to store individual timestamps. His misunderstanding of the way databases work is way more fundamental than what you're giving him credit for.

Comment: @joshstrike: It's entirely possible I'm being overly-generous in crediting OP's understanding "of the way databases work". OP does imply he's creating MySQL `EVENT` object; it's apparent that OP already has `CREATE TABLE` statement that works. The question was how to get the result from a SELECT to be part of an identifier in a DDL statement. The MySQL `PREPARE` statement isn't just for "prepared" DML statements; it can also be used to execute some DDL statements (only some, because there are some DDL statements that can't be executed), but I believe CREATE TABLE is supported.

Comment: fair enough, maybe at first glance it just seemed absurd as a backup method ... well, it does still seem crazy to create tables on the fly like this, and it terrifies me to think of anything that worked that way, especially using names based on a unix timestamp. I like to write software that will not eat itself if I die tomorrow. Someone should point him towards cron tasks and mysqldump. Stuffing a DB with weirdly named timed copies of itself is a horrendous backup strategy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad architecture. Generating tables on the fly is not something you should do.

Instead, create a single table with a timestamp column. For instance, if you would before have 3 tables with three timestamps A, B, and C, you now have one table with a timestamp column containing the values A, B, and C, respectively.